# Context.User is null in a Signalr 2.0 Hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using VS 2013 Express and the standard MVC5 template to create a new clean app. Authentication is enabled and I can log into the site just fine. I can see the user context in my controllers, but when I add Signalr I can't get the Hubs to register that authentication has take place.

Context.User in the hub is null. Using Signalr 2.0.2 and all related OWIN packages.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The resolution to the program was very simple. In my startup class I had the code in the wrong order.

This is what I had when it wasn't working:

```
    app.MapSignalR();
    ConfigureAuth(app);
```

However, this is the correct order to have Signalr work with authentication:

```
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.MapSignalR();
```

This may be a no-brainer for most, but I think it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Can you please share the ConfigureAuth method?