# Why is SignalR Context.User.Identity.Name empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684605/context-user-is-null-in-a-signalr-2-0-hub?rq=1) helped me fix a null `Context.User` value, but after fixing that,  `Context.User.Identity.Name` is empty.

Here is what I see in the Immediate Window for `Context.User.Identity`:

```
{System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity}
    AccessToken: {Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeAccessTokenHandle}
    Actor: null
    AuthenticationType: ""
    BootstrapContext: null
    Claims: {System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<get_Claims>d__95}
    CustomSerializationData: null
    DeviceClaims: Count = 0
    Groups: null
    ImpersonationLevel: Anonymous
    IsAnonymous: true
    IsAuthenticated: false
    IsGuest: false
    IsSystem: false
    Label: null
    Name: ""
    NameClaimType: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
    Owner: null
    RoleClaimType: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid"
    Token: {0}
    User: null
    UserClaims: Count = 0
```

I am suspicious that `IsAuthenticated: false` has something to do with it, but my authentication is handled in a SalesForce wrapper, not via the typical `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` code - I've searched my repo and we do not use `SetAuthCookie` anywhere. I am successfully authenticated based on what I see in my localhost web page.

What must be done to populate / get access to the Identity `Name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your suspicion is correct with regard to the IsAuthenticated property.  If you are calling your hub (or web API) without any kind of token (OAuth/JWT), cookie, windows auth, etc, the Claims/Identity information will not be populated.  [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization) an overview of SignalR hub authentication/authorization. I've had success using the authorization filter (the one contained in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR) on the Signalr hub, along with a Bearer token passed in on the call:

```
 var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:50042/signalr");
 connection.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

The authorization filter gets invoked very early on in the web api pipeline.  The token will be decrypted and the Thread Principle/Identity will be set.  However, this token was issued by my web api, so, it was able to be parsed.

I don't have any Salesforce experience, but, it sounds like your app setup is a bit different than what I recently did.  I assume your application is authenticating against the SalesForce API.  That token that comes back from Salesforce must then be used to authenticate/authorize calls against subsequent calls to the Salesforce API. However, you can't decrypt/parse that token to extract the claims (hopefully. otherwise that's not good).

Have you tried JWT with Salesforce (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5))?  Or with Web API, utilizing external authentication (example [here](https://thompsonhomero.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/creating-a-clean-web-api-2-project-with-external-authentication-part-2/))? You can probably pass the JWT back and forth between your client and the .NET Web Api that I assume is hosting the signalr hub, and use a custom authorization filter to parse the JWT token to authorize the call to the hub/set the Identity (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193171/jwt-authentication-in-signalr-net-core-without-passing-token-in-query-string) stackoverflow post for a start).

Hope this gets you rolling.